# Authorize.net TLS Disablement Notice nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl, authorize.net, tls1.2, pci-compliance

Few days back, i got a notice from **Authorize.net** to disable **TLS 1.0** and **TLS 1.1**

i am using nodejs here is my code in app.js to disable the TLS1.0 and TLS 1.1

```
var sslOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/private.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/STAR_crt.com.crt'),
  secureProtocol: 'SSLv23_server_method',
    secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1,
  ca: [
            fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot_1.crt'),
            fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot_2.crt'),
            fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot_3.crt')
        ],
      ciphers:[
    "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384",
    "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384",
    "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256",
    "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256",
    "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256",
    "DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256",
    "HIGH",
    "!aNULL",
    "!eNULL",
    "!EXPORT",
    "!DES",
    "!RC4",
    "!MD5",
    "!PSK",
    "!SRP",
    "!CAMELLIA",
    "!3DES"
].join(':'),
  //ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt'),
  requestCert: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};
```

But it seems i am missing something. I did SSL labs test after 30 hours and i got following results:-

[image]

Any idea what i need to do?

Thanks

Comment: What does what you get on SSL Labs have to do with YOUR code? This is their server telling you what capabilities another server has. Nothing in your code is going to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `SSLv23_server_method` to `TLSv1_2_server_method`

```
var sslOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/private.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/STAR_crt.com.crt'),
  secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_server_method',
    secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1,
  ca: [
            fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot_1.crt'),
            fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot_2.crt'),
            fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot_3.crt')
        ],
      ciphers:[
    "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384",
    "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384",
    "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256",
    "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256",
    "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256",
    "DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256",
    "HIGH",
    "!aNULL",
    "!eNULL",
    "!EXPORT",
    "!DES",
    "!RC4",
    "!MD5",
    "!PSK",
    "!SRP",
    "!CAMELLIA",
    "!3DES"
].join(':'),
  //ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt'),
  requestCert: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The announcement was that Authorize.Net will stop supporting TLS 1.1 and 1.0 in February 2018, you need to ensure your system can make a TLS 1.2 connection by then.  You can test this by connecting to the sandbox which only supports TLS 1.2.